# Thwart babel transpiler for one line

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, babeljs

The Babel transpiler is a very useful tool to get code written in modern JavaScript syntax to run in old browsers. However, I find myself needing to work *around* it rather than *with* it.

I have two very different versions of the same library (CkEditor4 and CkEditor5, in case that matters). CkEditor5 doesn't run in IE11, even with Babel and polyfilling. CkEditor4 is full of inline handlers, so we have to turn our CSP off on the pages it is on.

Obviously, the solution here is to use Code-splitting - load 5 on the browsers that support it, and 4 in the browsers that don't. I want to use Feature Detection, not Browser Detection, because there are more browsers than just IE11 that can't run 5, and some of them actually visit our site.

However, when I add my feature detection line into my code base:

```js
const supports = typeof Symbol === "function" && typeof Symbol() === "symbol";
console.log(supports);
```

Babel transpiles it to:

```js
"use strict";

var _typeof = typeof Symbol === "function" && typeof Symbol.iterator === "symbol" ? function (obj) { return typeof obj; } : function (obj) { return obj && typeof Symbol === "function" && obj.constructor === Symbol && obj !== Symbol.prototype ? "symbol" : typeof obj; };

var supports = typeof Symbol === "function" && _typeof(Symbol()) === "symbol";
console.log(supports);
```

Which returns true if Symbol is *polyfilled*, as well as when it is natively supported. So IE11 is loading CkEditor5, which doesn't work.

There doesn't seem to be a way to Feature Detect the const keyword without eval (which our CSP also forbids), and our bundling process runs *all* files in it through Babel.

I've tried:

```
const s = "Symbol";
const supports = typeof self[s] === "function" && typeof self[s]() === s;
```

And similar obsfication methods, but Babel keeps seeing through them. Is there any way I can get it to leave this one line alone?

Comment: How are you configuring Babel? You can probably disable that specific `typeof-symbol` handling in general, unless you're actually relying on it it somewhere else in your own code. Also, what version of Babel are you on?

Comment: @loganfsmyth I'm using the built-in version of Babel that comes with React.NET. Sorry, I can't seem to find *which* version that is, or how to configure it, in their documentation...